# JAVA - erro ao iniciar aplicação com Hibernate

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, conexão

Estou tendo problemas ao iniciar minha aplicação com Hibernate. Estou programando em Java, utilizando o Eclipse.

Mensagem de erro:

> set 20, 2017 2:40:36 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final} set 20, 2017 2:40:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found set 20, 2017 2:40:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver
>   resolveEntity WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate
>   namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration.
>   Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration
>   instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at
>   any time. set 20, 2017 2:40:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} set 20, 2017 2:40:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver
>   resolveEntity WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate
>   namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use
>   namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead. 
>   Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
>   set 20, 2017 2:40:38 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) set 20, 2017 2:40:38 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>   at URL [jdbc:mysql:192.168.0.0/CCIBD] set 20, 2017 2:40:38 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root,
>   password=****} set 20, 2017 2:40:38 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false set 20, 2017
>   2:40:38 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
>   Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create
>   requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   Factory.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:17)     at
>   Model.ModelUsuario.(ModelUsuario.java:15)   at
>   Executaveis.ExeUsuario.main(ExeUsuario.java:10)
>
> **Caused by:** org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create >requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>     at Factory.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:13)    ... 2 more
>
> **Caused by:** org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC
>   Connection [jdbc:mysql:192.168.0.0/CCIBD]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:20)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
>     ... 16 more

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"=//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<!-- Database Dialect & Driver for Oracle 9G-->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

<!-- Database Details-->
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">1997</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql:192.168.0.0/CCIBD</property>

<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">root</property>

<!-- Additional Properties -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<!-- Table Mapping --> 
<mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate-mapping Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="HibUsuario" table="Usuario">
<meta attribute="class-description">
This class contains the USUARIO mapping.
</meta>

<id name="cpf" type="int" column="cpf">
 <generator class="native"/> 
</id>

<property name="usuario" type="string" column="usuario" not-null="true"/>
<property name="senha" type="string" column="senha" not-null="true"/>
<property name="permissao" type="string" column="permissao" not-null="true"/>

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

HibernateUtil:

```
package Factory;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
try {
    sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
}
catch (Throwable ex){
    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
}
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

Banco de dados:

```
create table Usuario(
cpf int not null,
usuario varchar(75),
senha varchar(25),
permissao varchar(30),
primary key(cpf),
constraint FK_FuncUser foreign key(cpf) references funcionarios(cpf)
);
```

Comment: `<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>` eu **acho** que 1 é muito pouco. Coloca algo entre 5 e 10 e veja se funciona

Comment: Não funcionou, tentei todos de 5 a 10.

Comment: O seu endereço do mysql é este mesmo 192.168.0.0? Normalmente finais 0 e 255 são utilizados para broadcast de rede. Verifique se o seu mysql está com a porta habilitada para o seu host.